# Non-web dev jobs, especially for someone well past college age

Tags: software-industry, career-switch

I'm basically the target market for a lot of bootcamps: I'll be 40 this year, I don't have a CS (or any) degree, and I'd like to switch over to coding. I enjoy what programming I have done (I've got years of experience with a couple proprietary and limited scripting languages on obscure platforms nobody cares about), and it can be done remotely and without having to relocate, which is more or less a requirement for me. I live in a populated area and could manage a job that was partly in office, partly remote, but being gone 9-5 every day is not an option for me. (Edit: I'm in California, but not the Bay Area or LA.)

To be honest, though, I'm not especially interested in webdev. Still, given my circumstances and requirements, is webdev (either self taught or through a bootcamp) realistically my only option?

Comment: What ARE you interested in?

Comment: Umm... I'm not entirely sure what's out there, honestly. I like the idea of working closer to the hardware and squeezing out a lot of performance. I'm also interested in game design. Whenever I look up what sorts of careers are currently available, it's all webdev, webdev, HFT, webdev, webdev, embedded systems, webdev, and games (with a warning to not go into that area).

Comment: Embedded programming often does not involve scripting at all. The development approach is quite different. And similar could be said of high performance work. Just a comment. I don't think the skills transfer easily.

Comment: You will probably need more experience with something actually used in the industry.   If you want to go close to the hardware, you might consider working on a Raspberry Pi to control relays and read sensors.  Learn git (this is extremely important) and put a portefolio on Github.

Comment: Can you add a location please? We regularly have questions about "can I be a developer doing a bootcamp" and apparently, in different parts of the world it's very different.

Comment: Added it. I'm in California, but not the Bay Area or LA.

Comment: Just a personal anecdote - but 'retraining' a competent 'scripter' into a competent embedded firmware developer is a daunting task. There are so many bad habits you can get away with in python or whatever, which end up turning into serious issues in embedded code.

Answer (score 1):

Most of those web apps, at least the interesting ones, have back-end servers and services doing the heavy lifting. There are still plenty of jobs in those areas.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if you can get a job after self-teaching any programming other than web development?

YES!

Here's a short list of development areas that pay very well, allow remote work, and only require a demonstration of skill:

- iOS
- Android
- Database administration
- Systems administration / DevOps (Linux, Apache, etc)
- Cloud admin (AWS, GCC, Azure, etc)

There are many others too. "Webdev" is a super generic and broad term.

Find a niche you like and start there.

You can safely pitch yourself as a junior developer in that area if you've had a few months of practice and a few basic demo projects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - it's definitely possible.

Some of the areas you mention, though, may take skills you want to build.  High performance systems (often that's embedded work), involve a degree of depth on how the computer or system handles processing, memory and computation.  I'm not saying a degree in CS is required, but often it takes some demonstrated capability in these areas and a degree in CS is one way to show them.  I'm not entirely sure you'll find a bootcamp that covers this.  A way to get there might also be volunteer/open source projects into libraries with high grade performance requirements, where you're learning hands on and for free.

It also comes to mind that basic scripting skills and the ability to self-teach on obscure (or proprietary!) languages are a good fit for system administration and professional services where you have to bend two systems to fit one another.  That can be in the web space but doesn't have to be - I would suspect there are still plenty of non-web corporate systems that need this skill set.

Web dev *is* a really big space these days, and it certainly feels like more and more stuff is getting heaved into the web.  Because it's growing so rapidly, and also because many jobs in that space to not need a wildly in depth knowledge of all of computer science/software engineering - it's definitely a big funnel for entry level jobs.  I'm somewhat interested on what you dislike about it -- since it's a big enough space that it holds a lot of different types of roles and people.